# Context sensitive grammar

Tags: grammar

Noam Chomsky - formal languages - type 1 - context sensitive grammar

Does AB->BA violate the rule? I assume it does.
A -> aAB does not violate condition?
aAB->ABc violates condition?

Comment: Could you rewrite your question to be more clear? It is hard to understand precisely what is your problem.

Comment: Which rule? AB->BA is indeed context sensitive. But maybe you'd better rephrase the question before Brad starts telling us his views on immigration.

Comment: How about context sensitive answers? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_grammar

Comment: how AB->BA is context sensitive? iAr -> iBr is not satisfied, explanation why would be difficult(now when I am thinking about long description I've written it seems people don't know formal definition at all), but I've never seen any example for context sensitive grammar where this reverse relation exists..

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that it isn't context free, which is what I thought you were asking.

Answer (score 1):

Using the wikipedia link provided, you can answer each question if you can map your production rules to the form:

iAr -> ibr, where A is a single non-terminal, i and r are (possibly empty) strings of terminals and non-terminals, and b is a non-empty string of terminals and non-terminals.

In other words, look at each of your rules, and try to make suitable choices for i, A, r, and b.

Before we look at your questions, let's look at some hypothetical examples:

Is CRC -> CRRRRRC a valid context-sensitive rule?

Yes. I can choose i=empty, A=C, r=RC, and b=CRRRR. Note, I could have made other choices that work, too.

Is xYz -> xWzv a valid context-sensitive rule?

No. There is no choice for i, A, and r that allow a match. If I chose i=x A=Y, r=z, and b=W, that trailing v screws things up.

Is xY -> xWzv a valid context-sensitive rule?

Yes. I can choose i=x, A=Y, r=empty, and b=Wzv.

This is the scheme you should use to answer your questions. Now, let's look at those:

1. AB -> BA: Assume you choose either A or B to be your single non-terminal. The choice fixes i and r (one will be empty, the other will be the non-terminal you didn't choose). Is there a string of the form ibr that can match based on how you fixed i and r? In other words, can you choose the string to replace b that maps to your rule?
2. A -> aAB. I hope the choice of your single non-terminal on the left is intuitively obvious. This choice will again fix i and r. Does the right map to a suitable ibr form where b is a nonempty string of terminals and nonterminals?
3. aAB -> ABc. Again, choose A or B to be your single non-terminal. This fixes i and r. Is there a choice that allows you to choose a suitable ibr?

Comment: THANKS A LOT, I cannot understand if 'A'AB => AB'B' is allowed, if order is important then it is incorrect if not then it is correct, we should have i and r on both sides, or if we have just 'i' on LHS we can have only 'i' on RHS too, but not 'r'? Wikipedia lists Bb=>bB, as context sensitive.                                             Again thanks, very much.

Comment: What I mean is that we can't have LHS i = RHS r, in fact we can't even have r if it is not in LHS, that is why 'A'AB => AB'B' is still unclear for me.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Order is important. I was trying to not be too explicit because of the homework tag (how far is too far?). Are you using a textbook for this assignment? If so, which one? My grammar theory course was mostly handwritten notes by the professor, so I sympathize if you have no textbook.